# Playing Catherine on PSNow with Keyboard & Mouse

Tags: catherine, playstation-now

Can I play Catherine on PSNow on Mac (on Parallels) with Keyboard & Mouse?

Will this configuration work? I heard that some games simply cannot be played without a controller?

Comment: Can somebody explain why my question is getting downvoted? What the heck.

Comment: Maybe they wonder why you haven't simply tried it for yourself.  Is it a question of whether you'd purchase it or not?  Do you have the keyboard and mouse already?  Maybe they thought it looked like info you'd find elsewhere on the interwebs.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr Not without additional software

I don't know what functionality Parallels offers, but as of the time of writing, PS Now on PC **only** officially supports the Dualshock 4 controller for input. Some non-Playstation controllers are supported, and some are not (from personal experience, the X-Box 360 and X-Box Elite controllers are, Steam Controllers and Dualsense 5 are not). Anything that is not a DS4 will not have touchpad/gyro functionality.

However, if you're willing to sink some effort (and money) into this endeavor - there is a paid piece of software, [reWASD](https://www.rewasd.com/) (no affiliation). It adds a virtual DS4 controller and allows you to map non-supported controllers or keyboard/mouse inputs to the virtual controller. I have not personally tried using it to play PS Now with a keyboard and mouse, but I have successfully used it to "trick" my PC into thinking a Steam Controller was a DS4 and used it to play PS Now games (I have had limited success mapping any input to the virtual touch pad but the default, out of the box mappings are perfectly serviceable).

Comment: I'm aware this question is >4 years old, but trying to get PS Now on PC working in 2021 doesn't seem to be any easier than it was in 2017. So far it has been an exercise in frustration and at this point I've spent enough money on it that it might have been cheaper to just buy a PS4 in the first place.